# CURL Command Line SFTP Upload - Specify Destination Filename

Tags: curl

I'm trying to upload a file using command line Curl. Uploading a file (without renaming) works fine:

```
curl -1 -v -k "sftp://some.domain.com:1234" --user "username:password" -T "my_local_file.txt" 2>&1
```

But is it possible to specify a **different** destination filename? I'd like to save the file on the remote server with a different name. Is this possible?

At the moment I'm renaming the file locally; uploading it and then naming it back. Not ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Apologies. I'm running this curl command as part of a php script that generates CSV files and sends them via FTP and SFPT to various remote servers. So I guess maybe that blurs the lines a little bit. But I understand that CURL is a command line tool generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -T flag allows you to specify the local file, and you can specify the remote path and filename directly in the URL.

Like so:

```
curl -1 -v -k "sftp://some.domain.com:1234/remote_path/remote_filename" --user "username:password" -T "local_filename"
```

This will upload my_local_file.txt from your local system to some_folder on the remote server, the file will be savd as new_remote_file.txt and you won't have to rename the file locally before and after the upload.